# How to fix a blank update my details link in the recurring payments receipt?

Tags: civicontribute, recurring-contributions, eway

I am providing a recurring payments option through the eway credit card gateway and the agileware recurring payments extension.

```
eWay_Recurring (au.com.agileware.ewayrecurring) 1.5.2
```

The template looks like it is loaded from here web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/4.6.10.msg_template/message_templates/contribution_online_receipt_html.tpl

The %1 link is blank in

```
You can update billing details for this recurring contribution by <a href="%1">visiting this web page</a>
```

How do we fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Fuzion did some work to improve eWay recurring using their **RapidDirect, Rapid & Shared** solutions. The code is now available in the [Omnipay Extension](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.omnipaymultiprocessor).

AgileWare helped fund the development of this but can't comment on whether that implies it is their preferred solution now.

Comment: I tried omnipay. Works for eway, but doesn't seem to have the recurring payment in the 'single currency' version that had the parameters that match the existing gateway settings. I'll have to have a look at RapidDirect. Some limitations are mentioned here https://civicrm.org/blog/eileen/rethinking-payment-processing

Answer (score 1):

If you post a bug report to the Github repo we'll take a look, https://github.com/agileware/au.com.agileware.ewayrecurring/issues

Comment: Good on you Justin